# When is angularjs cookieStore updated with new cookie?

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I am currently implementing login functionality in my app. I use AngularJS and `$cookieStore`. I get a cookie from the server when I make an ajax request to authenticate the user. I want to use this cookie in `success()` to set up the user in my Auth services. I use chrome developer tools to pause right after I ask for the cookie like this:

```
var cookieUser = $cookieStore.get('user');
```

but it turns out to be `undefined`, **but** a chrome watch on `unescape(document.cookie)` shows a cookie `"user"` is set.

If I run the request twice: `$cookieStore.get('user')` returns the previous cookie.

Why is `$cookieStore` not updated with the cookie I just received?

Comment: I know it's not related to the question, but you wrote "Sceince" in your profile. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AngularJS' uses an asynchronous `$watch` callback to write cookies.](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular-cookies.js) So you either need to wrap your cookie reading inside a `$timeout`, or access the data without `$cookieStore.get`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So there is no way to use `$cookieStore.get()` without using delays like `$timeout`?

Comment: Nope. A workaround could be to return the user in the server response. Also note: if $cookieStore sets a cookie, it is available immediately through $cookieStore.get, without delay. So you could consider moving cookie-setting to the front-end.

Comment: I use [query-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) as a workaround. `$.cookie('user')` is available immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

After the login was successful in my appplication I had ,of course, to transition to a state 'main.index' and in its **resolve** object I wasn't able to get the authentication cookie with $cookies object(angular), but I was able to see it in document.cookie.

I think $cookies are refreshed a tiny bit latter than the $.cookie that **@swenedo** mentioned.

Using $.cookie from jquery worked for me.